# Runge–Kutta integration for quaternion kinematrics

Tags: integration, quaternions, runge-kutta-methods

How can I use the Runge-Kutta integration method for quaternions

###### Kinematics (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.02508.pdf)

Incremental rotation $\Delta \theta = \omega_n \Delta t$

$  Exp(\omega \Delta t) = q\{\omega \Delta t\} = e^{\omega \Delta t /2 } = \begin{bmatrix} cos(||\omega|| \Delta t/2)\\
\frac{\omega}{||\omega||} sin(||\omega|| \Delta t/2)\end{bmatrix}$

Difference equation
$q_{n+1} = q \otimes q\{\omega \Delta t\}$

Differential equation
$\frac{dq}{dt} =\dot{q} = \frac{1}{2} q \otimes \omega$

###### Runga-Kutte of 4th order

$x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{\Delta t}{6} \big( k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4 \big)$

$k_1 = f(t_n, x_n)$

$k_2 = f(t_n + \frac{1}{2} \Delta t,\; x_n + \frac{\Delta t}{2} k_1 )$

$k_3 = f(t_n + \frac{1}{2} \Delta t,\; x_n + \frac{\Delta t}{2} k_2 )$

$k_4 = f(t_n + \Delta t,\; x_n + \Delta t \cdot k_3 )$

How can i apply the differential equation $\dot{q}$ to the Runga-Kutta method?

Comment: Yes, you can use it as it is, in the end you have a (mostly) linear first-order system. But you will lose the unit radius. This can be corrected via normalization after each step, or you could investigate the idea of geometric integration methods. That is, you compute a multiplicative update similar to the discrete case, where an appropriately configured integration happens in the exponent.

Comment: Thank you for the info :)